# Casting to a File Pointer

Tags: c, fuse, file-pointer

I'm setting up the FUSE filesystem, and I need to get a file pointer to any open files so that I can encrypt them as they get written. The FUSE system uses a special struct. One of the components of the struct is called fh and is of type uint64_t. When a file is opened, it is captured in an int variable as you can see in the following code:

```
/* File open operation */
int bb_open(const char *path, struct fuse_file_info *fi)
{
    int fd;   
    fd = open(path, fi->flags);
    fi->fh = fd;
    return fd;
}
```

This fi struct is available to me in the write function, and I'm hoping that I can use it to create a file pointer that I can pass to my encryption function. Here is the code for the write function as I have it set up at the moment:

```
/* Write data to an open file */
int bb_write(const char *path, const char *buf, size_t size, off_t offset,
         struct fuse_file_info *fi)
{
    char* password;
    FILE* fp;
    //malloc and instantiate password
    fp = (FILE*) fi->fh; //my lame attempt to get a file pointer
    return encrypt(<inpFilePtr>, <outFilePtr>, 1, password);
}
```

Finally, the signature of my encryption function looks like this:

```
extern int encrypt(FILE* in, FILE* out, int action, char* key_str);
```

I'd like to take that fi->fh variable and turn it into a file pointer so that I can use it as my input file pointer argument. Since it was originally created by an "open" operation, it seems like there should be a way to do this, but I can't make it work.

Can anyone help? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

File descriptors and `FILE *` pointers aren't the same thing.  A `FILE *` pointer is a pointer to an opaque type provided by your C implementation - the APIs that deal with `FILE *` (`fopen`, `fread`, `fwrite`, `fclose`, etc.) are part of standard C.  File descriptors, on the other hand, are operated on using the POSIX system calls (`open`, `read`, `write`, `close`, etc.) that are often used to implement the C-level abstractions.

Luckily there are functions that let you get one from the other.  In your case, you'll want to use [`fdopen(3)`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/fdopen/) to get a `FILE *` from the file descriptor.  If you wanted to go the other way, you'd want to look into [`fileno(3)`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/fileno/).